# SQL method taking a long time

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm using SQLite with C#.

I use the following method to loop through a list of tv shows and their episodes and insert them into the database.  It ends up entering about 1200 rows and takes 2 minutes 28 seconds.  It feels like that's kinda slow so I would like people to look over my method and see if i'm doing something stupid (I'm sorta new to this).

```
public void InsertAllEpisodes(List<TVDBSharp.Models.Show> showList)
    {

        using (SQLiteConnection dbconnection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string seasonNumber;
            string episodeNumber;
            string insertShowSQL = @"INSERT INTO AllEpisodes (Key, ShowName, ShowId, EpisodeName, SeasonEpisode) VALUES (@Key, @ShowName, @ShowId, @EpisodeName, @SeasonEpisode)";

            foreach (var show in showList)
            {
                foreach (var episode in show.Episodes)
                {
                    if (episode.SeasonNumber != 0)
                    {
                        string seasonEpisode = "default";
                        if ((episode.SeasonNumber != 0) && (episode.SeasonNumber.ToString().Length == 1)) { seasonNumber = "0" + episode.SeasonNumber.ToString(); }
                        else { seasonNumber = episode.SeasonNumber.ToString(); }
                        if (episode.EpisodeNumber.ToString().Length == 1) { episodeNumber = "0" + episode.EpisodeNumber.ToString(); }
                        else { episodeNumber = episode.EpisodeNumber.ToString(); }
                        seasonEpisode = seasonNumber + episodeNumber;
                        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(insertShowSQL, dbconnection);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Key", show.Id + seasonEpisode);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ShowName", show.Name);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ShowId", show.Id);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EpisodeName", episode.Title);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SeasonEpisode", seasonEpisode);
                        dbconnection.Open();
                        try
                        {
                            command.ExecuteScalar();
                        }
                        catch (SQLiteException ex)
                        {
                            if (ex.ResultCode != SQLiteErrorCode.Constraint)
                            {
                                File.AppendAllText(programDataPath + "SQLErrors.txt", ex.Message + "\n");
                            }
                        }
                        dbconnection.Close();
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: You're opening & closing the database connection within an inner `foreach` loop - this should be done outside the loops. Also, what's the count of `showList` and `show.Episodes` respectively?

Comment: In addition to what Rhys said, how many rows are already in your table and do you have a lot of indexes on that table?

Comment: @Rhys 6 Shows, 1300 Episodes

Comment: @ohiodoug It creates the database before inserting these so it's blank.  I delete it before I run it everytime

Comment: I moved `dbconnection.Open()` and `dbconnection.Close()` outside the loop and it took 2 minutes 18 seconds

Comment: Remember that multiple `SQLiteCommand` instances are being created. I would either dispose of it, or instantiate it outside of the inner loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read up on and used `sqlComm = new SQLiteCommand("begin", dbconnection)` and `sqlComm = new SQLiteCommand("end", dbconnection)` and it inserted it in less than 1 second.

```
public void InsertAllEpisodes(List<TVDBSharp.Models.Show> showList)
    {

        using (SQLiteConnection dbconnection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
        {

            dbconnection.Open();
            string seasonNumber;
            string episodeNumber;
            string insertShowSQL = @"INSERT INTO AllEpisodes (Key, ShowName, ShowId, EpisodeName, SeasonEpisode) VALUES (@Key, @ShowName, @ShowId, @EpisodeName, @SeasonEpisode)";
            SQLiteCommand sqlComm;
            sqlComm = new SQLiteCommand("begin", dbconnection);
            sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            foreach (var show in showList)
            {
                foreach (var episode in show.Episodes)
                {
                    if (episode.SeasonNumber != 0)
                    {
                        string seasonEpisode = "default";
                        if ((episode.SeasonNumber != 0) && (episode.SeasonNumber.ToString().Length == 1)) { seasonNumber = "0" + episode.SeasonNumber.ToString(); }
                        else { seasonNumber = episode.SeasonNumber.ToString(); }
                        if (episode.EpisodeNumber.ToString().Length == 1) { episodeNumber = "0" + episode.EpisodeNumber.ToString(); }
                        else { episodeNumber = episode.EpisodeNumber.ToString(); }
                        seasonEpisode = seasonNumber + episodeNumber;
                        sqlComm = new SQLiteCommand(insertShowSQL, dbconnection);
                        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("Key", show.Id + seasonEpisode);
                        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("ShowName", show.Name);
                        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("ShowId", show.Id);
                        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("EpisodeName", episode.Title);
                        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("SeasonEpisode", seasonEpisode);
                        try
                        {
                            sqlComm.ExecuteScalar();
                        }
                        catch (SQLiteException ex)
                        {
                            if (ex.ResultCode != SQLiteErrorCode.Constraint)
                            {
                                File.AppendAllText(programDataPath + "SQLErrors.txt", ex.Message + "\n");
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
            sqlComm = new SQLiteCommand("end", dbconnection);
            sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            dbconnection.Close();

        }

    }
```